# How to handle Index out of range in a better way

Tags: c#

My code was giving me Index out of Range exception for a certain input. Below is the problematic code:

```
string[] snippetElements = magic_string.Split('^');

string a = snippetElements[10] == null ? "" : "hello";
string b = snippetElements[11] == null ? "" : "world";
```

For that particular  input, array snippetElements had only one element in it, hence while trying to index 10th and 11th element, I got the exception.

For now, I have introduced the following check:

```
if (snippetElements.Length >= 11)
{
    string a = snippetElements[10] == null ? "" : "hello"; 
    string b = snippetElements[11] == null ? "" : "world";
}
```

Can someone suggest a better way to write this check. Somehow the number 11 is not looking good in the code.

Comment: I think, as the question's name suggests, that it's more suitable to ask/migrate the post to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/?as=1)

Comment: I disagree @Trustme-I'maDoctor, I'd say it is just a badly named question!

Comment: @KingCronus Possibly, then just re-naming the title would be nice just so there's no confusion :)

Comment: Any reason you are putting a shim in for one particular case? Aren't you just asking for future workarounds? Give us more info on the actual use of the function, and we might be able to help better.

Comment: Incidentally, the way you currently have it will not necessarily prevent an exception.  If the length is exactly 11, then this will still produce an exception.

Comment: Your question is too vague. If "normal" operation assumes there are 10/11 items, why would there only be one? There needs to be some kind of background information.

Answer (score 15):

Yes this is an old post, but still helpful. You could use this which I think is cleaner:

```
string a = snippetElements.ElementAtOrDefault(10) ?? "hello"; 
string b = snippetElements.ElementAtOrDefault(11) ?? "world";
```

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone suggest a better way to write this check. Somehow the
>   number 11 is not looking good in the code.

Well you are accessing the element with `11` index, if you have that index in your variable then you can use that in your check, otherwise `11` is fine in your check. Your check should be `if(index < snippetElements.Length)`

Something like:

```
int index = 11;

if(index < snippetElements.Length)
{
   string b = snippetElements[index] == null ? "" : "world";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`snippetElements[11]` is the 12th element.

```
if (snippetElements.Length >= 12)
```

As long your are actually using the [10] and [11] indexes it doesn't look wrong to use the 12 in the if statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can generalize the problem to an *extension method* like this:

```
public static class ArrayExtensions
{
    public static bool TryIndex<T>(this T[] array, int index, out T result)
    {
        index = Math.Abs(index);

        result = default(T);
        bool success = false;

        if (array != null && index < array.Length)
        {
            result = (T)array.GetValue(index);
            success = true;
        }

        return success;
    }
}
```

And convert your code to:

```
string[] snippetElements = magic_string.Split('^');

string a = null;
string b = null;

if (snippetElements.TryIndex(10, out a) && snippetElements.TryIndex(11, out b))
{
}
```

Or, more like your source code and using the `TryIndex(...)` extension method:

```
string[] snippetElements = magic_string.Split('^');

string a = null;
string b = null;

snippetElements.TryIndex(10, out a);
snippetElements.TryIndex(11, out b);

a = a ?? "hello"; // Null coalesence ?? operator is great!
b = b ?? "world";
```

It makes the array indexed access safer since your code won't never throw `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

#### Note that this extension method will work for any kind of array, regardless of its type! Either if its a value type (int, byte...) or a reference type (string, your own classes...).

Comment: Very pretty :) Maybe a bit overkill ;)

Comment: @RvdK Yeah, but as OP was asking for an alternative... If you don't use something like this _overkill_, there're few options...

Comment: True, it is a good alternative :) Therefore I gave it an upvote

Comment: @RvdK Thanks! I was thinking for some minutes how I would improve the OP's approach and I thought about that :D

Answer (score 0):

The logic here is wrong.
If your [Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) method produces less than 12 elements your indexing on the array `snippetElements` could go only from zero to (Length - 1) of the array.

In that case there aren't elements at index 10 or 11. And, in any case, if the `snippetElement.Lenght` is equal or greater than 12, then the elements in the array can't be null. Or they contain a string or they will be empty strings.
You could just write

```
string a = snippetElements.Length >= 12 ? "hello" : string.Empty; 
string b = snippetElements.Length >= 12 ? "world" : string.Empty;
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be late now, but for any one else who's having the same problem, that's how I solved it. I usually use this logic inside a for loop.

```
int index = 10;
string a = (index < snippetElements?.Length) ? snippetElements[index] : string.Empty;
```

`snippetElements?.Length` checks if snippetElements is not empty then it calls its Length property. Accessing Length property of an empty array results in an exception.
`snippetElements[index]` (you could replace this with "hello" as in your example) is accessed only if the index is in the bound of an array. Otherwise, it assigns String.Empty to a.